# Web camera not working with fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, webcam, fedora-15

I'm using fedora 15 on my HP G42 laptop, I didn't install any particular packages for access web camera. Does the default OS support access web camera or Do I need to install any software package for that?

Answer (score 1):

Fedora should support your web camera out of the box.

To verify that your camera is working, you could try executing the following command in a terminal

```
mplayer tv://
```

A window should pop up with your webcam stream.

If you don't have mplayer installed, you can install it by running the following command:

```
yum install mplayer
```

There's also a more user-friendly webcam application called **Cheese** located in **Applications -> Sound and Video -> Cheese**

If you don't have already have Cheese, you can install it by executing the following command in a terminal.

```
yum install cheese
```

Comment: I did that, here is the output I get:
`MPlayer SVN-r35234-4.7.2 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing tv://.
TV file format detected.
Selected driver: v4l2
 name: Video 4 Linux 2 input
 author: Martin Olschewski <olschewski@zpr.uni-koeln.de>
 comment: first try, more to come ;-)
v4l2: unable to open '/dev/video0': No such file or directory
v4l2: ioctl set mute failed: Bad file descriptor
v4l2: 0 frames successfully processed, 0 frames dropped.
`

Comment: But mplayer is installed on my laptop